# PHP code getting commented to HTML comments in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
<?php

use function PHPSTORM_META\type;

$api = 'api.com';
$token  = 'abcd-abcd-abcd';

$options = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => "Token: $token"
    ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($options);

$resp = file_get_contents($api, false, $context);
$resp = json_decode($resp, true);
?>
```

The above stuff is getting commented out as HTML comments and rest as string. So can you please say how to solve this issue. I searched in online but didn't get the exact answer.

**WordPress version is 5.9.4**
**No Plugins**

```
<!--?php
 use function PHPSTORM_META\type;

$api = 'api.com';
$token  = 'abcd-abcd-abcd';

$options = [
    'http' =--> "['method' => 'GET','header' => "Token: $token"]];$context =stream_context_create($options);$resp = file_get_contents($api, false, $context);$resp =json_decode($resp, true);?>"
```

Comment: Which version of WordPress are you using? What are your plugins? Have you tried disabling plugins? Is this above code stuff you've written yourself or is it part of a plugin?

Comment: need more context.

Comment: will update soon

Comment: `<!--?php` did you mean `<?php`?

Comment: `<!--?php` is usually what you get in your browser, when it received `<?php` from the server. So most likely, your PHP code did not get executed as such, but only passed on the the client as _text_. But why, is currently impossible to tell, with the amount of info we have.

Comment: @CBroe sure will give more details like WP version, plugins, etc soon

Comment: The WordPress **version is 5.9.4**

Comment: **No Plugins!**

Comment: Are you putting this code in page content from the backend? or is it in one of the php files from the theme or plugin?

Comment: @VijayHardaha I am adding the code in the **custom HTML inside modules**